# Listbox/listview as folder browser?

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net 2013 how do you make a listbox to be a browser of a directory where you can't leave the directory, but only browse inside of it - open folders in it and go back up to the root level? Similar to warcraft 3 where you choose a map and can open folders and go back. Andbasically any game with editor has such option.
Or if it's not possible with lsitbox is it possible with listview?

Comment: A `ListBox` does what it does. It displays a list of items and it lets you select one or more of those items. It's up to you to retrieve the items yourself, whatever they may be.  If you want those items to be a list of subfolders of a folder then you need to learn how to retrieve the subfolders of a folder.  That's got nothing to do with a `ListBox`. That's what you need to research. Once you have that list, you display it in the `ListBox` the same way as any other list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to take into account when building something like this, here are a couple of areas and pointers to help you on your way...

[Get Directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) This article will help you get a list of directories.

[Get Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) Once you have folders, you'll need to get the files too!

Put it all together... more tricky! You'll have to use some imagination and a lot of googling to understand how it all looks. Depending on your level, start of with lists, use [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx) or simply listboxes to begin. Understand what data is being populated.

If you're up for the challenge...[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) is an amazing custom control. If you can get your head round it, it can be very easy to manage.

Keep googling and asking! Theres always help out there!

Hth Chicken